# It won't create a Java VM (JNI)

Tags: java, c++, jvm, java-native-interface

My simple command line app:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
 JavaVM *jvm;
 JNIEnv *env;
 JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;
 JavaVMOption options[1];
 options[0].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=."; //Path to the java source code
 vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6; //JDK version. This indicates version 1.6
 vm_args.nOptions = 1;
 vm_args.options = options;
 vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = 0;

 jint ret = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void**)&env, &vm_args);
 return 0;
}
```

gives me:

> ```
> Error occurred during initialization of VM
> Unable to load native library: Can't find dependent libraries
> ```

The breakpoint at "return 0" is never reached. jvm.dll resides in same directory as my command line app.

I don't get it what's wrong. Any Ideas? Thanx in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that your problem is answered by [this question](http://java.sun.com/products/jdk/faq/jni-j2sdk-faq.html#move) in the Sun JNI FAQ.

TL;DR version: Don't move the JVM installation's DLLs.

Comment: Thank you very much! That was the issue. I looked by Dependency Walker and just copied it. Now added it to path and works. Stupid misleading error message.

Comment: I don't get how this answer and your comment reply apply to the problem. Could you elaborate on the fix? What did you copy where? I don't see a "classic" dir in my jre or jdk's bin dir :-(

Comment: @Wouter - the point is that you must not move the DDLs around.  If you do, then the JVM gets confused, as the FAQ explained.  (The actual layout of the JRE installation directory tree may have changed, which could be why you cannot see a "classic" directory.  But the FAQ's key point remains valid: don't move the DLLs around.)

Answer (score 3):

In my experiance,

**Cause**

Maybe, JVM.DLL is located in below path.

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_xx\jre\bin\client\    (a)

and below folder contains many DLLs the JVM needs;

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_xx\jre\bin\           (b)

So, the `JMV.DLL` (that you dynamically linked) tries to search the all `DLL`s in its parent folder(b).

**Solution**

Don't copy JVM.DLL to the same folder in which your .exe is located!!!!
Check you PATH system variable. It have to contain (a) and (b) paths.
If so, maybe your .exe will be executed successfully.